# DAX: Average by 2 level/Rollup

Tags: average, dax

This is my requirement and I'm new to DAX, any help would be appreciated:

[image: Sample data, DAX calculation: Average by Emp and Role]

Comment: Thanks Alexis helping me. But the final average require on Role basis i.e 29.875. Not matching  with your result.  Waiting for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AVERAGE` function inside of `CALCULATE` to get what you want.

```
AvgByEmp = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(RoleTab[Value]), ALL(RoleTab[EmpID]), RoleTab[Value] <> 0)
```

The `ALL(RoleTab[EmpID])` filter removes the `EmpID` filter context (but keeps the `RoleID` context) and the `RoleTab[Value] <> 0` filter removes the zero values from the calculation.

[image: AverageMeasure]